# Print Queue values using a loop

Tags: queue, computer-science

```
 package q;
import java.util.*;
class GFG
{
static class Queue
{
   static Stack<Integer> s1 = new Stack<Integer>();
   static Stack<Integer> s2 = new Stack<Integer>();
   static void Q(int x)
   {
       while (!s1.isEmpty())
       {
           s2.push(s1.pop());  
       }  
       s1.push(x);
       while (!s2.isEmpty())
       {
           s1.push(s2.pop());  
       }
   }
   static int dQ()
   {
       if (s1.isEmpty())
       {
           System.out.println("Q is Empty");
           System.exit(0);
       }
       int x = s1.peek();
       s1.pop();
       return x;
   }
}
public static void main(String[] args) { 
   Queue q = new Queue();
   q.Q(100);
   q.Q(200);
   q.Q(300);
   System.out.println(q.dQ());
   System.out.println(q.dQ());
   System.out.println(q.dQ());
}
}
```

I'm doing an assignment and it is required to use two stacks to build a queue. I've done it but I have one question. How can I print the values using a loop instead of printing them line by line? For some reason, it doesn't work. I tried writing:

```
while(q.dQ()!){
   System.out.println(q.dQ());}
```

but it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can define another method in your Queue class to check if the queue is empty. Something like:

```
static boolean isEmpty(){
   // returns true is both stacks are empty
   if(s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()){
       return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then you can print the queue with a loop, as:

```
while(! q.isEmpty()){
   System.out.println(q.dQ());
}
```